# How to save datas from custom form in joomla article

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hi I have created custom form in joomla article with html.When i click the submit button i need to validate the form and also to call the controller of the com_content.From the controller i need to save the form field datas to mysql database through model.How to do this.Please guide me.

```
    <form id="slideshow-form" class="form-validate"  method="post" name="adminForm">
```

Name

Your mobile number

Your email address

What is your city of residence?

Comment: So did you create a new form or did you just add fields to the existing article form edit.php?

Comment: You probably need to use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

for custom form it's better to use one of joomla form builder extensions like [Chronoform](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508)